# Referencing numpy array locations within if statements

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I have the following section of Python:

```
for j in range(0,T):
    for x in xrange(len(index)):
        for y in xrange(x+1,len(index)):
            if index(y) == index(x):

            continue
```

For which I have been attempting to translate successfully from a MATLAB equivalent. In matlab, this operation is simple as follows:

```
    for iter = 1:T
    for i = 1:length(index)
    for j = i+1:length(index)
        if index(j) == index(i)
            continue;
        end
```

However, when I attempt to execute my code I receive a "numpy.ndarray object is not callable" error. Why does this arise, and how would I go about writing this in a proper python manner to successfully execute?

Comment: I'm guessing that means you want `index[y] == index[x]` (square brackets, not parenthesis)

Comment: Also I think python's `len` and matlab's `length` are different. In python, `len` of an array is `numpy.size(array, axis=0)` in matlab `length` is `MAX(SIZE(MATRIX))`.

Comment: @BiRico - You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `index` is an array of some sort, but when you do `index(y)` and `index(x)`, Python thinks you're trying to call a function `index()` using `x` and `y` as parameters, respectively.

If you're trying to simply access the elements, use `index[x]` and `index[y]`.